# How long it takes to design a nice font

Tags: fonts, designers

Wondering how long (rough estimate) it would take one who is skilled with vector tools to design a full featured font with font hinting and everything.

Comment: I'm afraid this is really too broad to be properly answered but the shortest I've seen was two weeks full-time (9am to 11pm) with a team of 4 designers in a student context with a highly skilled mentor.  [Crafting Type](http://craftingtype.com/) gives a 3-day intensive workshop but I'm not sure it includes all you have listed.

Comment: That said, don't underestimate the value of taking a step back to re-assess your work. I had a classmate back in the day who had been working on a serif for the past 4 years as a hobby. There really is no limit to how much time you can dedicate to something like designing a font...

Comment: I can only speak for myself. I'm NOT a font designer, but I'm skilled in Adobe's applications and I have more than basic knowledge on fonts. Still it was a great challenge when I agreed to make a font for a customer. The customer only paid for about 12 hours of work but in reality I spend more than 40 hours. It was a VERY simple font based on the nordic runes and only caps. I also have a personal project where I after 40+ hours still only have the capital letters and no kerning. It's incredibly time consuming!

Comment: It varies. Give yourself a treat and read about designers of nice fonts and how they work their craft: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_type_designers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how many glyph's you do and how much kerning you need to make. If you design a font with only the English character set punctuation and no need for kerning (or autokeerning) then you can get away with a few hours.

Indeed I have designed a font with the constraint that I could only use a text editor (think notepad) and a command line call to font forge for the task. **Using only my mobile phone*** (sic). By limiting myself to uppercase characters +, -, ± and diameter sign it took me about 2 hours (except that the S was a bit horrible so i had to redesign it) to do this. It has horrible kerning but works.

This is close to what the font looked like at that point, the S is different but not much (S is the only character that was hard to make with the text editor and feedback time i had), some of the other glyphs have also very minor edits**:

[image]

**Realistically** though, a few weeks to a few months is more accepted. But can take years.

* Although is did prepare 1 hour to get the tools in place.

** here is what one glyphs design looks like in the text editor after it was done:

```
glyph
%# B
newpath
25 0 moveto
25 100 lineto
67 100 67 60 20 arct
67 60 50 60 20 arct
25 60 lineto 
75 60 75 0 30 arct
75 0 55 0 30 arct
25 0 lineto
stroke
```

Comment: Using only your mobile phone!!! That is amazing, wow :D I would love to see that, serious designing / editing from the phone, always wondered about that, seems hard.

Answer (score 2):

It depends the font type and the family styles included in the design.

The factors to consider:

- The size of the family
- The complexity of the project
- The personal workload

---

## 24 hours

Hard to believe but James Barnard certifies it [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/designing-a-font-from-scratch-and-submitting-it-to-google-fonts-in-24-hours-152a30c57095). Even being a relatively simple design and only one style, 24 hours I think it's too tight (and unhealthy :-)). But the step by step description is very interesting and can help to make a font design schedule.

[image]

---

## Three months

In the nineties, each issue of the quarterly design magazine [**Emigre**](https://www.emigre.com/Magazine) used to come with several new fonts designed exclusively, this means that [Zuzana Licko](https://www.emigre.com/Designer/ZuzanaLicko) and her team designed at least five fonts in three months. And of course, the magazine design. It's also true that most of these fonts have only one style.

[image: Emigre]

---

## One month

I use to be guided by the time that the international typographic design competitions give to present works to the contest. The most relevant give a period between six months and a year. What I think is quite correct and even exaggerated.

Dedicating exclusively to the design of the font, once defined the conceptual and formal basis, with four families styles, I think between two weeks and a month is a right time. Always depends the design type, it's not the same a *Simple Geometrical Font* than a *Roman Family*.